# Correct way to retrigger loadTokens in Ktor client

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

In my mobile app, I have a singleton Ktor `HttpClient` with bearer authentication configured as such:

```kotlin
HttpClient(…) {
    install(Auth) {
        bearer {
            sendWithoutRequest { requestBuilder -> some condition }
            loadTokens(tokensStorage::getTokens)
            refreshTokens {
                performTokenRefresh(oldTokens.refreshToken)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now consider the following flow:

1. The user opens the app while the tokens stored in my `tokenStorage` are not valid.
2. The `HttpClient` loads the tokens from `tokenStorage` and the request fails with a 401.
3. The `HttpClient` tries to perform a refresh but it fails too because the refresh token is invalid.
4. The user is redirected to the login page, logs in, and the new valid tokens are stored in `tokenStorage`.
5. Now from the app the user can retry the call that failed in points 2-3. However this will fail forever until the app is closed, because the `HttpClient` never tries to call `loadTokens` anymore. Indeed, as far as I can see from the source code, `loadTokens` is called only once and then never again.

I found out a couple of ways to solve the issue.

The first one is to manually retrieve `BearerAuthProvider` from the `HttpClient` and clear the token myself like in the following snippet, but it seems like a hacky workaround:

```kotlin
httpClient.plugin(Auth).providers
    .filterIsInstance<BearerAuthProvider>()
    .first().clearToken()
```

Another one is to manually load the current token from my `tokenStorage` in `refreshToken` and disregard what get passed in `this@refreshTokens.oldTokens`:

```kotlin
refreshTokens {
    val currentRefreshToken = tokenStorage.getTokens().refreshToken
    performTokenRefresh(currentRefreshToken)
}
```

However this means that the client will do an unnecessary call to the refresh API, while having already a valid token pair (obtained from the login).

So my question is: is there a cleaner way to handle the situation? Am I misusing Ktor?

Comment: I think the only adequate way to solve this problem is to clear tokens manually (your first approach) since all methods in the `AuthTokenHolder` class is internal and the `tokensHolder` property is private.

Comment: I went with clearing the tokens manually as well, any time my tokens change (whether from a log-out or new log-in or whatever).

Comment: There's an issue on YouTrack about this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4759/Auth-BearerAuthProvider-caches-result-of-loadToken-until-process-death