# Ktor client, how correctly set access token after receiving it?

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor-client

Here is my ktor client setup

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideHttpClient(
    localService: LocalService,
): HttpClient {

    val chuckerInterceptor = ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(App.appContext)
        .collector(ChuckerCollector(App.appContext))
        .maxContentLength(250000L)
        .redactHeaders(emptySet())
        .alwaysReadResponseBody(false)
        .build()

    val okhttpEngine = OkHttp.create {
        addInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
    }
 

    return HttpClient(okhttpEngine) {

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(
                Json {
                    prettyPrint = true
                    isLenient = true
                    useAlternativeNames = true
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    encodeDefaults = false
                    explicitNulls = false

                }
            )
        }

        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = 10_000
            connectTimeoutMillis = 10_000
            socketTimeoutMillis = 10_000
        }

        install(Logging) {
            logger = object : Logger {
                override fun log(message: String) {
                    Log.v("Logger Ktor =>", message)
                }
            }
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }

        install(ResponseObserver) {
            onResponse { response ->
                Log.d("HTTP status:", "${response.status.value}")
            }
        }

        install(DefaultRequest) {
            header(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)
          
        }

        defaultRequest {

            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
          
        }

        install(Auth) {
            bearer {
                refreshTokens {

                    val token = client.get {
                        markAsRefreshTokenRequest()
                        url(BASE_URL + REFRESH_TOKEN)
                        parameter("refreshToken", localService.getRefreshToken())
                    }.body<AuthResponseDto>()
                    BearerTokens(
                        accessToken = token.accessToken.token,
                        refreshToken = token.refreshToken.token
                    )
                }
                loadTokens {

                    BearerTokens(
                        accessToken = localService.getAccessToken().orEmpty(),
                        refreshToken = localService.getRefreshToken().orEmpty(),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is according to access token. When i receive access and refresh tokens after success auth, i saved it to local storage (DataStore). Then when i try to make next request, there no token in request, but when i reopen application all is ok. As i understood ktor cannot runtime get token from local storage and update client after i have saved it ? How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to gpunto's question ([Correct way to retrigger loadTokens in Ktor client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72064782/correct-way-to-retrigger-loadtokens-in-ktor-client)), one solution is to manually retrieve **BearerAuthProvider** from the **HttpClient** and clear the token yourself like in the following snippet:

```
httpClient.plugin(Auth).providers
.filterIsInstance<BearerAuthProvider>()
.first().clearToken()
```